# Calculating pH of solution

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, aqueous-solution, ph

> What is the $\mathrm{pH}$ when you dissolve equal amounts of $\ce{NaHCO3}$ and $\ce{Na2CO3}$ in water?

When both of the compounds are dissolved, we will have equal amounts of $\ce{HCO3-}$ and $\ce{CO3^2-}.$ But how do we go from this to actually calculating the $\mathrm{pH}$?

In the solution manual, it is given that $\mathrm{pH} = \mathrm pK_\mathrm{a2} = 10.33$ (It seems like the $\mathrm pK_\mathrm{a2}$ value of $\ce{CO2}$ has been used here — why?), but I don't understand how they can just conclude with that.

#### My attempt

So, we will start with equal amounts of $\ce{HCO3-}$ and $\ce{CO3^2-}$. We have the following equilibrium:
$$\ce{HCO3- <=> H+ + CO3^2-}$$
We can set up an equilibrium expression (and cancel) until we are left with $K_\mathrm{a2} = [\ce{H+}]$ and $-\log K_\mathrm{a2} = \mathrm pK_\mathrm{a2} = \mathrm{pH} = -\log[\ce{H+}]$.

Now, what I don't understand is why are we using the $\mathrm pK_\mathrm{a2}$ of $\ce{CO2}$? Why that value?

Comment: We have a policy which states that ‎you should show your thoughts and/or efforts into solving the problem. It'll make us certain that ‎we aren't doing your homework for you. 
Basically any question with the wording your question has is considered homework; it needn't be literally one. Self-study questions, puzzles etc. also count as homework. 

Don't worry, they're not banned. But, we require a minimal effort. Otherwise, this question may get closed.‎ Please [edit] in your full reasoning or thoughts on this.

See [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/141/7448)

Comment: Ask yourself what Ka2, resp pKa2 means.

Comment: I have updated my first post with a better attempt.

Comment: You may want to look up the Henderson-Hasselbach equation.

Comment: @Kdbmvp Ask yourself, how is Ka2 for CO2 defined.

Comment: Actually we haven't learned the Henderson-Hasselbach equation, isn't it possible to solve it without it? And is my first attempt wrong?

Comment: So Ka,2 for CO2 is defined as Ka,2 = [H+][HCO3(-2)]/[HCO3(-)], so I guess I have it now. What I don't quite understand is why it is written pkA,1 and pkA,2 values for CO2 in tables. Couldn't it have stood H2CO3(carbonic acid) instead of CO2?

Comment: In fact, there are 2 versions of pKa1, one for H2CO3, one for CO2. pKa2 is for HCO3-.

Comment: So what's the difference between them?

Comment: Is not Google or Wikipedia search faster ? Search for the carbonic acid.